# Local images not set at it's perticular index in collectionview

Tags: ios, uikit

In  `collectionView` at first `reloadData`, data set correctly in cell but if we reload `collectionView` after performing any task the local images change there places .I don't know why but images change there places (indexPath).

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    -> UICollectionViewCell {

      let cell = songListCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "SongCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as? SongCollectionViewCell

      let getArtistOfWeekObject = self.getArtistOfWeekObjectList?.game?.locks![indexPath.row]

      print(getArtistOfWeekObject as Any)


      if getArtistOfWeekObject?.status == 1 {
        cell?.lockImg.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "select")
        cell?.numberLbl.text = "song \(indexPath.row + 1)"
      } else if getArtistOfWeekObject?.playable == 1 {
        cell?.lockImg.isHidden = true
        cell?.numberLbl.text = "song \(indexPath.row + 1)"
      } else {
        cell?.lockImg.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "white_lock")
        cell?.numberLbl.text = "song \(indexPath.row + 1)"
      }

      return cell!
  }
```

here the lockImg change its indexPath after reload

Comment: is `lock` actually `Array`? Did you change in some way your `locks `?

Comment: When and where did you reload first time your `songListCollectionView `?

Comment: lock is simply a imageView having single images for according to conditions and these images are from assets . its not any array of images @vpoltave

Comment: songListCollectionView reload in method where data from server get. i always reload from there only

Comment: Do you perform any action inside `SongCollectionViewCell` ?

Comment: yes according to condition i have to set imgaes in lockimg.